# How to set the ruby version in circleCI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, circleci

I am using circleCI for CI with the following .yml file

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    machine:
      ruby:
        version: 2.4.4
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: bundle install
      - run: echo "hello"
```

The error message is

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.4
Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.4
```

My Gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.4'
```

What is the proper way to set ruby version?

Comment: What is your machine ruby version? You can update the `ruby` version `2.4.4` on your machine or remove this line `ruby '2.4.4'` from your Gemfile

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using `CircleCI 2` but you're setting the ruby version using the `CircleCI 1` way.

As stated in this [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/testing-ios/#custom-ruby-versions), to set the ruby version in `Circle CI 2`, you can either create a `.ruby-version` file in your rails app and commit the file or you can create it from a build step:

```
run:
  name: Set Ruby Version
  command:  echo "ruby-2.4.4" > ~/.ruby-version
```

Answer (score 4):

*disclaimer: I'm a CircleCI Developer Advocate*

Your config example is mixing CircleCI 2.0 and 1.0 config syntax and this is causing the issue.

If you want to use Ruby 2.4.4 in a CircleCI 2.0 build and you want to use our premade Docker image, then your config should look like this:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.4
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: bundle install
      - run: echo "hello"
```

The above example is for the Linux environment. If you're doing macOS builds, then @e_a_o's answer will help you there.

Answer (score 1):

I referred this [CircleCI docs](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/unrecognized-ruby-version/) and created a file .ruby-version that explicitly stated the version to be used i.e. 2.4.4 and it works. The content was

2.4.4